# Should virtualbox count as Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, windows

Over my time on this site, I have seen around ten or twelve questions around this main circle. People are running Windows with Ubuntu on virtualbox, and are having issues. They then assume that virtualbox is perfect, and immediately come to ask for help. That's just a little backstory. My actual question is, are there too many possible errors that virtualbox can cause, to the point where AskUbuntu should not support them? I feel like there are infinitely many problems Virtualbox or VMware could cause, and that the AskUbuntu community may not have the ability to help these people. What are your guys' thoughts on this?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that *some* people *might* have purely Windows-related problems when running it as a guest under Ubuntu is a reason to outlaw virtualisation questions.

We can deal with the few off-topic ones on a case by case basis.